# Как правильно вывести данные с помощью document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript

Есть простая задачка, в поле человек вводит число, ему должно вывести степень этого числа с 2 по 4. Изначально вывод информации был реализован с помощью `document.write`. Что вызывает некие неудобства, решил реализовать это с помощью `document.getElementById` но столкнулся с тем, что выводится только число во второй степени, хотя с `document.write` такой проблемы не было, та еще и результат мгновенно пропадает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я неправильно прописал

```
<script>
function valid(form){
    var step;
    var chislo = form.chislo.value;
    var fail = false;
    if (chislo == "" || chislo == " "){
        fail= "Вести число трудно, да?";
        document.write(fail);
        return false;
    } else {
        for(step=2; step<=4; step++){
            var summa=Math.pow(chislo, step);
            document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = chislo + "<sup>" + step + "</sup>"  + " = " + summa + "; ";
            document.write(chislo + "<sup>" + step + "</sup>"  + " = " + summa + "; ");
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post" name="test" onsubmit="valid(this)">
    <input type="text" name="chislo" placeholder="Ваше число" id="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Узнать степень">
</form>
<div id='step'></div>
```

Comment: На каждом этапе цикла содержимое div заменяется на новое значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать так.

Как видите, я добавил три блока с уникальным `id`, т.к. выводился только последняя степень (что и логично). Так же, при событии `onsubmit` в форме я добавил [`return false;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037069/what-is-the-meaning-of-onsubmit-return-false-javascript-jquery).

```js
function valid(form){
    var step;
    var chislo = form.chislo.value;
    var fail = false;
    if (chislo == "" || chislo == " "){
        fail= "Вести число трудно, да?";
        document.write(fail);
        return false;
    } else {
        for(step=2; step <= 4; step++){
            var summa = Math.pow(chislo, step);
            document.getElementById(step).innerHTML = chislo + "<sup>" + step + "</sup>"  + " = " + summa + "; ";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="test" onsubmit="valid(this); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="chislo" placeholder="Ваше число" id="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Узнать степень">
</form>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<div id='4'></div>
```